# Liquibase is not compiling package in oracle dbms

Tags: oracle, liquibase

Problem: Using liquibase 4.0.0, trying to create package in oracle database & it does create the package but dose not compile it implicitly.
My sql file (1_changelog.oracle.sql) has below statement:

```
    --liquibase formatted sql
    --changeset sm:202012041410-01 splitStatements:false
    create or replace PACKAGE MY_SCHEMA.PKG1 AS
        PROCEDURE PROC_REQUEST_LOCKOUT_STATUS(
            in_my_request_number IN VARCHAR2
        );
        END PKG1;
    create or replace PACKAGE BODY BMF_SS_MAIN.PKG_BMFMTM AS
       ....
       END PKG_BMFMTM
```

please suggest if someone already has faced such issue.

Comment: This will create the package, and Oracle will "compile" it implicitly; you shouldn't have to do anything else. What are you seeing that leads you to believe that it didn't compile? Note that I don't see a *package body* - the actual procedure code -  in your example; "create package" will only create the header, so you've only done half the work here.

Comment: we have body also & we are able to manually compile it after liquibase deploy it

Comment: in my case liquibase is not compiling the package..

Comment: What version of liquibase are you using?  I believe you need Liquibase Pro to work with stored logic.